# Linear regression coefficients from covariance matrix

Tags: regression, covariance

In case of two random variables $y,x$ we have that the best linear fit $y = \beta x + \epsilon$ satisfies 
$$
  \beta = \frac{\mathrm{Cov}(x,y)}{\mathrm{Cov}(x,x)}.
$$
That is, if I known covariance matrix for $x$ and $y$ I can derive betas. Does the same argument apply also in case $x$ is multi dimensional?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in the multivariate case,

$$\mathbf{y} = \beta^\top \mathbf{x} + \varepsilon,$$

you have

$$\mathbf{\beta} = \mathbf{C}_\mathbf{yx} \mathbf{C}_\mathbf{xx}^{-1},$$

where

$$\text{Cov}\left( \begin{array}{c} \mathbf{x} \\ \mathbf{y}\end{array} \right)
= \left( \begin{array}{cc} \mathbf{C}_\mathbf{xx} & \mathbf{C}_\mathbf{xy} \\ \mathbf{C}_\mathbf{yx} & \mathbf{C}_\mathbf{yy} \end{array} \right)$$

is the covariance matrix belonging to $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for this?